# Understanding where the continuity equation comes from

Tags: probability, ordinary-differential-equations

Suppose we have a random variable $X$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^k$ and that this random variable has a smooth density $p(x)$ over all of $\mathbb{R}^k$. Suppose further that I have a smooth vector field $\mathbf{g} : \mathbb{R}^k\to\mathbb{R}^k$ and let $\phi_t(x)$ denote the flow of this vector field to time $t$ starting from initial position $\phi_0(x) = x$. It seems to be a result that if I transform $X_t\overset{\text{def.}}{=} \phi_t(X)$ then the density of $X_t$ obeys a continuity equations:
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} p_t(x) = -\text{div}(p_t \mathbf{g})
$$
How does one prove this result?

I actually know this result to be a special case of the Fokker-Planck equation governing stochastic differential equations. The proof I know for Fokker-Planck requires Dynkin's formula, stopping times, infinitesimal generators for diffusions, and operator adjoints. I have a feeling that a simpler proof should exist for the case wherein the diffusion coefficient is zero, as I have described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BOTTOM LINE UP FRONT**: You can apply the [Reynolds Transport Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_transport_theorem) to the scalar field $p$.

Fix $A\subset\mathbb{R}^k$. This set evolves according to the flow $\phi_t$: at time $t$, the "material points" that "occupied" $A$ at time 0, occupy the set $\phi_t(A)$. The integral of $p$ over $\phi_t(A)$ is
\begin{equation}
\int_{\phi_t(A)}p(t,x)dV.
\end{equation}

The Reynolds Transport Theorem shows that
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\phi_t(A)}p(t,x)dV = \int_{\phi_t(A)}\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,x)dV + \int_{\partial\phi_t(A)}p(t,x)\mathbf{g}(x)\cdot\mathbf{n}(x)dS,
\end{equation}
where $\partial\phi_t(A)$ is the boundary of $\phi_t(A)$, $\mathbf{n}(x)$ is the outward-facing unit normal vector at $x\in\partial\phi_t(A)$, and $dS$ is the differential area on $\partial\phi_t(A)$.

By the Divergence Theorem,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\partial\phi_t(A)}p(t,x)\mathbf{g}(x)\cdot\mathbf{n}(x)dS = \int_{\phi_t(A)}\textrm{div}(p(t,x)\mathbf{g}(x))dV.
\end{equation}

So far we have
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\phi_t(A)}p(t,x)dV = \int_{\phi_t(A)}\left[\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,x) + \textrm{div}(p(t,x)\mathbf{g}(x))\right]dV.
\end{equation}

If the probability attached to each evolving set is constant, then the time derivative on the left-hand side is zero for all (well-behaved) sets $A$. The only way this can be true for such a wide class of sets is if the integrand is identically zero (or zero almost everywhere, if you're into that sort of thing).

---

---

The Reynolds Transport Theorem

---

We can express the integral over $\phi_t(A)$ as an integral over $A$ as follows:
\begin{equation}
\int_{\phi_t(A)}p(t,\tilde{x})dV(\tilde{x}) = \int_{A}p(t,\phi_t(x))J(t,x)dV(x),
\end{equation}
where $dV(\tilde{x})$ it the volume measure on $\phi_t(A)$, $dV(x)$ is volume measure on $A$, and $J$ is the Jacobian determinant of the map $x\mapsto\phi_t(x)$.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{A}p(t,\phi_t(x))J(t,x)dV(x) = \int_{A}\frac{d}{dt}\left[p(t,\phi_t(x))J(t,x)\right]dV(x)
\end{equation}

---

Let $y(t,x) = \phi_t(x)$.
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}p(t,\phi_t(x)) &=~ \frac{d}{dt}p(t,y(t,x))\\
&=~ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,y(t,x)) + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\frac{\partial p}{\partial x_i}(t,y(t,x))\frac{\partial y_i}{\partial t}(t,x)\\
&=~ \frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + (\nabla p)\cdot\mathbf{g},
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where the spatial argument of each term in the last line is $y(t,x) = \phi_t(x)$.

---

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}J(t,x) &=~ \frac{d}{dt}\det\left(\textrm{grad}~\phi_t(x)\right)\\
&=~ \frac{d}{dt}\det\left(\textrm{grad}~y(t,x)\right)\\
&=~ \textrm{div}\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}(t,x)\right)J(t,x)\\
&=~ \textrm{div}\left(\mathbf{g}(y(t,x))\right)J(t,x)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

---

When we put these terms together, the integrand over $A$ is seen to be
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}\left[p(t,y(t,x))J(t,x)\right] &=~ J(t,x)\frac{d}{dt}p(t,y(t,x)) + p(t,y(t,x))\frac{d}{dt}J(t,x)\\
&=~ J\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + (\nabla p)\cdot\mathbf{g}\right) + pJ~\textrm{div}(\mathbf{g})\\
&=~ J\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + (\nabla p)\cdot\mathbf{g} + p~\textrm{div}(\mathbf{g})\right)\\
&=~ J\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t} + \textrm{div}\left(p\mathbf{g}\right)\right).
\end{split}
\end{equation}

---

In summary,
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{\phi_t(A)}p(t,\tilde{x})dV(\tilde{x}) &=~ \frac{d}{dt}\int_{A}p(t,\phi_t(x))J(t,x)dV(x)\\
&=~ \int_{A}\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,\phi_t(x)) + \textrm{div}\left(p(t,\phi_t(x))\mathbf{g}(\phi_t(x))\right)\right)J(t,x)dV(x)\\
&=~ \int_{\phi_t(A)}\left(\frac{\partial p}{\partial t}(t,\tilde{x}) + \textrm{div}\left(p(t,\tilde{x})\mathbf{g}(\tilde{x})\right)\right)dV(\tilde{x})
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Comment: Yes, I've encountered Reynolds transport theorem as a proof technique for continuity equations which even hold on Riemannian manifolds with the Riemannian divergence operator. I do feel that I have to recurse one level down now in order to understand Reynolds transport theorem though.